# Python: Can I set pdb.set_trace() in imported function

Tags: python, debugging, python-import, pdb

I am running a python script. In this script, I import a function from another module like:

```
from preprocessing import train_batch
```

the `train_batch` function is called in the script I am running. Now to check the `train_batch` in more details, I find the `preprocessing.py` and insert `pdb.set_trace()` in `train_batch` in the `preprocessing.py`, but it doesn't work.

So I want to ask: can I use `pdb.set_trace()` in an imported module? If I can, then this must mean the module I found is wrong and I need to find the right place. If I cannot, then is there any good way to check imported function if necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere in Python code*. If it "doesn't work" I assume you mean that you never dropped into pdb. That means that line of code is not being executed.

You can use the 's' command in pdb to step into code, even if it's not your own. As long as it's Python and not C code, you should be just fine. I'm not sure what happens for the C code.

- except in a lambda. But in general, anywhere

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  `pdb.set_trace()` is just a function call; you can place it anywhere that you can put any other function call.